# Drawing color and depth images side by side in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I'm currently learning Vulkan and I'm trying to write an application that draws a scene and the scene's depth buffer side by side.

At first I thought to use a single subpass to render a frame with extent `(width/2) x height` and then use `vkCmdBlitImage` twice to copy the resulting frame and its depth image to the swapchain but I quickly discovered that swapchain images don't necessarily support `VK_IMAEG_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT`.

My current strategy is to use two subpasses in a single render pass.
The first subpass renders the resulting frame to the left side of the screen using a viewport and the second subpass takes the depth attachment of the first subpass as an input attachment and renders it to the right side of the screen.

My first issue is that this strategy seems incredibly wasteful because I have to use a depth image whose extent is `width x height` (instead of `(width/2) x height`) so if it were up to you, how would you implement this application?

My second issue is that the depth image isn't showing at all!

The color attachment is showing just fine on the left (and it also shows fine on the right if I switch between the viewports) but on the right (where the depth image should be) I get a `clearValue`-colored screen.
The depth buffer itself is working just fine (The objects on the screen are rendered in the correct order) and it also looks like the fragment shader is working fine (I tried writing different colors without using the input attachment and it worked).

I am running out of ideas where the problem could be, I think it's something to do with the subpass dependency becuase it looks like the depth values aren't getting written to the buffer (or are accessed before they are written).

Relevant code:

```c
/***************/
/* Render pass */
/***************/
{
    const VkAttachmentDescription attachments[] = {
        // Color attachment
        {
            .flags            = 0,
            .format           = swapchain->format,
            .samples          = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT,
            .loadOp           = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR,
            .storeOp          = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE,
            //.stencilLoadOp  = <uninitialized>,
            //.stencilStoreOp = <uninitialized>,
            .initialLayout    = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
            .finalLayout      = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR,
        },
        // Depth attachment / Input attachment
        {
            .flags          = 0,
            .format         = VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT,
            .samples        = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT,
            .loadOp         = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR,
            .storeOp        = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE,
            .stencilLoadOp  = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE,
            .stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE,
            .initialLayout  = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
            .finalLayout    = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL,
        },
    };

    const VkSubpassDescription subpasses[] = {
        // First subpass - Render "regular" frame
        {
            .flags                   = 0,
            .pipelineBindPoint       = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS,
            .inputAttachmentCount    = 0,
            //.pInputAttachments     = <uninitialized>,
            .colorAttachmentCount    = 1,
            .pColorAttachments       = (VkAttachmentReference[]) {
                { 0, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL },
            },
            .pResolveAttachments     = NULL,
            .pDepthStencilAttachment = (VkAttachmentReference[]) {
                { 1, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL },
            },
            .preserveAttachmentCount = 0,
            //.pPreserveAttachments  = <uninitialized>,
        },
        // Second subpass - Render depth image
        {
            .flags                   = 0,
            .pipelineBindPoint       = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS,
            .inputAttachmentCount    = 1,
            .pInputAttachments       = (VkAttachmentReference[]) {
                { 1, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL },
            },
            .colorAttachmentCount    = 1,
            .pColorAttachments       = (VkAttachmentReference[]) {
                { 0, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL },
            },
            .pResolveAttachments     = NULL,
            .pDepthStencilAttachment = NULL,
            .preserveAttachmentCount = 0,
            //.pPreserveAttachments  = <uninitialized>,
        },
    };

    const VkSubpassDependency dependencies[] = {
        {
            .srcSubpass      = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
            .dstSubpass      = 0,
            .srcStageMask    = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
            .dstStageMask    = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
            .srcAccessMask   = 0,
            .dstAccessMask   = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,
            .dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT,
        },
        {
            .srcSubpass      = 0,
            .dstSubpass      = 1,
            .srcStageMask    = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_LATE_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT,
            .dstStageMask    = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT,
            .srcAccessMask   = VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,
            .dstAccessMask   = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT,
            .dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT,
        },
    };

    const VkRenderPassCreateInfo create_info = {
        .flags           = 0,
        .attachmentCount = sizeof(attachments) / sizeof(attachments[0]),
        .pAttachments    = attachments,
        .subpassCount    = sizeof(subpasses) / sizeof(subpasses[0]),
        .pSubpasses      = subpasses,
        .dependencyCount = sizeof(dependencies) / sizeof(dependencies[0]),
        .pDependencies   = dependencies,
    };

    vulkan_result = vkCreateRenderPass(device, &create_info, NULL,
                                       &swapchain->renderPass);
    assert(vulkan_result == VK_SUCCESS);
}

/**************************/
/* Descriptor set layouts */
/**************************/
{
    // MVP matrices
    VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo create_info = {
        .flags        = 0,
        .bindingCount = 1,
        .pBindings    = (VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding[]) {
            {
                .binding            = 0,
                .descriptorType     = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER,
                .descriptorCount    = 1,
                .stageFlags         = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT,
                .pImmutableSamplers = NULL,
            }
        },
    };

    vulkan_result = vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(device, &create_info, NULL, &renderer->setLayouts.color);
    assert(vulkan_result == VK_SUCCESS);

    // Input attachment for depth image
    create_info.pBindings = (VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding[]) {
            {
                .binding            = 0,
                .descriptorType     = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_INPUT_ATTACHMENT,
                .descriptorCount    = 1,
                .stageFlags         = VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT,
                .pImmutableSamplers = NULL,
            }
    };

    vulkan_result = vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(device, &create_info, NULL, &renderer->setLayouts.depth);
    assert(vulkan_result == VK_SUCCESS);
}

/********************/
/* Pipeline layouts */
/********************/
{
    VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo create_info = {
        .flags = 0,
        .setLayoutCount = 1,
        .pSetLayouts = &renderer->setLayouts.color,
        .pushConstantRangeCount = 0,
        //.pPushConstantRanges = <uninitialized>,
    };

    vulkan_result = vkCreatePipelineLayout(device, &create_info, NULL, &renderer->pipelineLayouts.color);
    assert(vulkan_result == VK_SUCCESS);

    create_info.pSetLayouts = &renderer->setLayouts.depth;

    vulkan_result = vkCreatePipelineLayout(device, &create_info, NULL, &renderer->pipelineLayouts.depth);
    assert(vulkan_result == VK_SUCCESS);
}

/*************/
/* Pipelines */
/*************/
{
    size_t code_size;
    uint32_t *code;
    code = read_file("shaders/color_vert.spv", &code_size);
    VkShaderModuleCreateInfo shader_module_create_info = {
        .flags    = 0,
        .codeSize = code_size,
        .pCode    = code,
    };

    VkShaderModule vertex_module;
    vulkan_result = vkCreateShaderModule(device, &shader_module_create_info, NULL, &vertex_module);
    free(code);
    assert(vulkan_result == VK_SUCCESS);

    code = read_file("shaders/color_frag.spv", &code_size);
    if (code == NULL) {
        vkDestroyShaderModule(device, vertex_module, NULL);
    }

    shader_module_create_info.codeSize = code_size;
    shader_module_create_info.pCode = code;

    VkShaderModule fragment_module;
    vulkan_result = vkCreateShaderModule(device, &shader_module_create_info, NULL, &fragment_module);
    assert(vulkan_result == VK_SUCCESS);
    free(code);

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo stages[] = {
        {
            .flags               = 0,
            .stage               = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT,
            .module              = vertex_module,
            .pName               = "main",
            .pSpecializationInfo = NULL,
        },
        {
            .flags               = 0,
            .stage               = VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT,
            .module              = fragment_module,
            .pName               = "main",
            .pSpecializationInfo = NULL,
        }
    };

    const VkVertexInputBindingDescription vertex_binding_description = {
        .binding   = 0,
        .stride    = sizeof(struct Vertex),
        .inputRate = VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX,
    };

    const VkVertexInputAttributeDescription vertex_attribute_description[] = {
        // Position
        {
            .location = 0,
            .binding  = 0,
            .format   = VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT,
            .offset   = offsetof(struct Vertex, position),
        },
        // Color
        {
            .location = 1,
            .binding  = 0,
            .format   = VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT,
            .offset   = offsetof(struct Vertex, color),
        }
    };

    VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo vertex_input_state = {
        .flags                           = 0,
        .vertexBindingDescriptionCount   = 1,
        .pVertexBindingDescriptions      = &vertex_binding_description,
        .vertexAttributeDescriptionCount = sizeof(vertex_attribute_description) / sizeof(vertex_attribute_description[0]),
        .pVertexAttributeDescriptions    = vertex_attribute_description,
    };

    VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo input_assembly_state = {
        .flags                  = 0,
        .topology               = VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST,
        .primitiveRestartEnable = VK_FALSE,
    };

    VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewport_state = {
        .flags         = 0,
        .viewportCount = 1,
        .pViewports    = (VkViewport[]) {
            {
                .x        = 0.0f,
                .y        = 0.0f,
                .width    = (float) extent.width / 2,
                .height   = (float) extent.height,
                .minDepth = 0.0f,
                .maxDepth = 1.0f,
            },
        },
        .scissorCount  = 1,
        .pScissors     = (VkRect2D[]) {
            {
                .offset = { 0, 0 },
                .extent = { extent.width / 2, extent.height },
            },
        },
    };

    VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterization_state = {
        .flags                   = 0,
        .depthClampEnable        = VK_FALSE,
        .rasterizerDiscardEnable = VK_FALSE,
        .polygonMode             = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL,
        .cullMode                = VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT,
        .frontFace               = VK_FRONT_FACE_COUNTER_CLOCKWISE,
        .depthBiasEnable         = VK_FALSE,
        //.depthBiasConstantFactor = ,
        //.depthBiasClamp          = ,
        //.depthBiasSlopeFactor    = ,
        .lineWidth               = 1.0f,
    };

    const VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo multisample_state = {
        .flags                 = 0,
        .rasterizationSamples  = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT,
        .sampleShadingEnable   = VK_FALSE,
        .minSampleShading      = 1.0f,
        .pSampleMask           = NULL,
        .alphaToCoverageEnable = VK_FALSE,
        .alphaToOneEnable      = VK_FALSE,
    };

    VkPipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo depth_stencil_state = {
        .flags                 = 0,
        .depthTestEnable       = VK_TRUE,
        .depthWriteEnable      = VK_TRUE,
        .depthCompareOp        = VK_COMPARE_OP_LESS,
        .depthBoundsTestEnable = VK_FALSE,
        .stencilTestEnable     = VK_FALSE,
        //.front                 = <uninitialized>,
        //.back                  = <uninitialized>,
        //.minDepthBounds        = <uninitialized>,
        //.maxDepthBounds        = <uninitialized>,
    };

    const VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState attachments[] = {
        {
            .blendEnable         = VK_FALSE,
            //.srcColorBlendFactor = <uninitialized>,
            //.dstColorBlendFactor = <uninitialized>,
            //.colorBlendOp        = <uninitialized>,
            //.srcAlphaBlendFactor = <uninitialized>,
            //.dstAlphaBlendFactor = <uninitialized>,
            //.alphaBlendOp        = <uninitialized>,
            .colorWriteMask      = VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_G_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_B_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_A_BIT,
        }
    };

    const VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo color_blend_state = {
        .flags             = 0,
        .logicOpEnable     = VK_FALSE,
        //.logicOp           = <uninitialized>,
        .attachmentCount   = sizeof(attachments) / sizeof(attachments[0]),
        .pAttachments      = attachments,
        //.blendConstants[4] = <uninitialized>,
    };

    VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo create_info = {
        .flags               = 0,
        .stageCount          = sizeof(stages) / sizeof(stages[0]),
        .pStages             = stages,
        .pVertexInputState   = &vertex_input_state,
        .pInputAssemblyState = &input_assembly_state,
        .pTessellationState  = NULL,
        .pViewportState      = &viewport_state,
        .pRasterizationState = &rasterization_state,
        .pMultisampleState   = &multisample_state,
        .pDepthStencilState  = &depth_stencil_state,
        .pColorBlendState    = &color_blend_state,
        .pDynamicState       = NULL,
        .layout              = renderer->pipelineLayouts.color,
        .renderPass          = render_pass,
        .subpass             = 0,
        //.basePipelineHandle  = ,
        //.basePipelineIndex   = ,
    };

    vulkan_result = vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(device, NULL, 1, &create_info, NULL, &renderer->pipelines.color);
    assert(vulkan_result == VK_SUCCESS);
    vkDestroyShaderModule(device, fragment_module, NULL);
    vkDestroyShaderModule(device, vertex_module, NULL);

    code = read_file("shaders/depth_vert.spv", &code_size);
    assert(code != NULL);
    shader_module_create_info.codeSize = code_size;
    shader_module_create_info.pCode = code;
    vulkan_result = vkCreateShaderModule(device, &shader_module_create_info, NULL, &vertex_module);
    assert(vulkan_result == VK_SUCCESS);
    free(code);

    code = read_file("shaders/depth_frag.spv", &code_size);
    assert(code != NULL);
    shader_module_create_info.codeSize = code_size;
    shader_module_create_info.pCode = code;
    vulkan_result = vkCreateShaderModule(device, &shader_module_create_info, NULL, &fragment_module);
    assert(vulkan_result == VK_SUCCESS);
    free(code);

    stages[0].module = vertex_module;
    stages[1].module = fragment_module;

    vertex_input_state.vertexBindingDescriptionCount   = 0;
    vertex_input_state.vertexAttributeDescriptionCount = 0;

    viewport_state.pViewports = (VkViewport[]) {
        {
            .x        = (float) extent.width / 2,
            .y        = 0.0f,
            .width    = (float) extent.width / 2,
            .height   = (float) extent.height,
            .minDepth = 0.0f,
            .maxDepth = 1.0f,
        },
    };

    viewport_state.pScissors = (VkRect2D[]) {
        {
            .offset = { extent.width / 2, 0 },
            .extent = { extent.width / 2, extent.height },
        }
    };

    rasterization_state.cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_NONE;

    create_info.pDepthStencilState = NULL;
    create_info.layout             = renderer->pipelineLayouts.depth;
    create_info.subpass            = 1;

    vulkan_result = vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(device, NULL, 1, &create_info, NULL, &renderer->pipelines.depth);
    vkDestroyShaderModule(device, vertex_module, NULL);
    vkDestroyShaderModule(device, fragment_module, NULL);
    assert(vulkan_result == VK_SUCCESS);
}

/****************/
/* Depth images */
/****************/
{
    // renderer->depthImages is a wrapper around VkImage and VkImageView
    // renderer->depthImages.images is a VkImage array with image_count elements
    // renderer->depthImages.imagesViews are the views of the respective images
    wn_images_init(renderer->device /* also includes physical device for memory allocation */, image_count, VK_FORMAT_D32_SFLOAT, VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_INPUT_ATTACHMENT_BIT, extent, &renderer->depthImages);
}

/****************/
/* Framebuffers */
/****************/
{
    renderer->framebuffers = calloc(sizeof(VkFramebuffer), renderer->imageCount);
    assert(renderer->framebuffers != NULL);
    if (renderer->framebuffers == NULL) {
        return VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY;
    }

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < renderer->imageCount; i++) {
        const VkImageView attachments[] = {
            render_targets[i],
            renderer->depthImages.imagesViews[i],
        };

        const VkFramebufferCreateInfo create_info = {
            .flags = 0,
            .renderPass = render_pass,
            .attachmentCount = sizeof(attachments) / sizeof(attachments[0]),
            .pAttachments = attachments,
            .width = extent.width,
            .height = extent.height,
            .layers = 1,
        };

        vulkan_result = vkCreateFramebuffer(device, &create_info, NULL,
                                            renderer->framebuffers + i);
        assert(vulkan_result == VK_SUCCESS);
    }
}

/******************/
/* Uniform buffers */
/******************/
{
    wn_buffer_init(renderer->device, sizeof(struct UniformBufferObject) * renderer->imageCount,
                   VK_BUFFER_USAGE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_BIT,
                   VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT,
                   &renderer->uniformBuffer.buffers);
}

/*******************/
/* Descriptor pool */
/*******************/
{
    const VkDescriptorPoolSize pool_sizes[] = {
        { VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, renderer->imageCount },
        { VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_INPUT_ATTACHMENT, renderer->imageCount },
    };

    const VkDescriptorPoolCreateInfo create_info = {
        .flags         = 0,
        .maxSets       = renderer->imageCount * 2,
        .poolSizeCount = sizeof(pool_sizes) / sizeof(pool_sizes[0]),
        .pPoolSizes    = pool_sizes,
    };

    assert(vkCreateDescriptorPool(device, &create_info, NULL, &renderer->descriptorPool) == VK_SUCCESS);
}

/*******************/
/* Descriptor sets */
/*******************/
{
    VkDescriptorSetLayout layouts[renderer->imageCount];
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < renderer->imageCount; i++) {
        layouts[i] = renderer->setLayouts.color;
    }

    VkDescriptorSetAllocateInfo allocate_info = {
        .descriptorPool       = renderer->descriptorPool,
        .descriptorSetCount   = renderer->imageCount,
        .pSetLayouts          = layouts,
    };

    renderer->sets.color = calloc(renderer->imageCount, sizeof(VkDescriptorSet));
    assert(renderer->sets.color != NULL);

    vulkan_result = vkAllocateDescriptorSets(device, &allocate_info, renderer->sets.color);
    assert(vulkan_result == VK_SUCCESS);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < renderer->imageCount; i++) {
        layouts[i] = renderer->setLayouts.depth;
    }

    renderer->sets.depth = calloc(renderer->imageCount, sizeof(VkDescriptorSet));
    assert(renderer->sets.depth != NULL);

    vulkan_result = vkAllocateDescriptorSets(device, &allocate_info, renderer->sets.depth);
    assert(vulkan_result == VK_SUCCESS);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < renderer->imageCount; i++) {
        const VkDescriptorBufferInfo buffer_info = {
            .buffer = renderer->uniformBuffer.buffers.buffer,
            .offset = sizeof(struct UniformBufferObject) * i,
            .range  = sizeof(struct UniformBufferObject),
        };

        const VkDescriptorImageInfo image_info = {
            .sampler = VK_NULL_HANDLE,
            .imageView = renderer->depthImages.imagesViews[i],
            .imageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL,
        };

        const VkWriteDescriptorSet writes[] = {
            {
                .dstSet             = renderer->sets.color[i],
                .dstBinding         = 0,
                //.dstArrayElement  = <uninitialized>,
                .descriptorCount    = 1,
                .descriptorType     = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER,
                //.pImageInfo       = <uninitialized>,
                .pBufferInfo        = &buffer_info,
                //.pTexelBufferView = <uninitialized>,
            },
            {
                .dstSet             = renderer->sets.depth[i],
                .dstBinding         = 0,
                //.dstArrayElement  = <uninitialized>,
                .descriptorCount    = 1,
                .descriptorType     = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_INPUT_ATTACHMENT,
                .pImageInfo         = &image_info,
                //.pBufferInfo      = <uninitialized>,
                //.pTexelBufferView = <uninitialized>,
            },
        };

        vkUpdateDescriptorSets(device, sizeof(writes) / sizeof(writes[0]), writes, 0, NULL);
    }
}

/*******************/
/* Command buffers */
/*******************/
{
    renderer->commandBuffers = calloc(renderer->imageCount, sizeof(VkCommandBuffer));
    if (renderer->commandBuffers == NULL)
        return VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY;

    const VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo allocate_info = {
        .commandPool        = renderer->graphicsCommandPool,
        .level              = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY,
        .commandBufferCount = renderer->imageCount,
    };

    vkAllocateCommandBuffers(device, &allocate_info, renderer->commandBuffers);

    const VkCommandBufferBeginInfo begin_info = {
        .flags              = 0
        //.pInheritanceInfo = <uninitialized>,
    };

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < renderer->imageCount; i++) {

        vkBeginCommandBuffer(renderer->commandBuffers[i], &begin_info);

        const VkRenderPassBeginInfo render_pass_begin_info = {
            .renderPass      = render_pass,
            .framebuffer     = renderer->framebuffers[i],
            .renderArea      = {
                .offset = { 0, 0 },
                .extent = { extent.width, extent.height },
            },
            .clearValueCount = 2,
            .pClearValues    = (VkClearValue[]) {
                { { { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f } } }, // Grey background
                { { { 1.0f, /*<uninitialized>*/ } } },
            },
        };

        vkCmdBeginRenderPass(renderer->commandBuffers[i], &render_pass_begin_info, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

        vkCmdBindPipeline(renderer->commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, renderer->pipelines.color);
        // Vertex and index buffers are in one VkBuffer. First the vertices and then the indices
        vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(renderer->commandBuffers[i], 0, 1, &renderer->vertexIndexBuffer.buffer, (VkDeviceSize[]) { 0 });
        vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(renderer->commandBuffers[i], renderer->vertexIndexBuffer.buffer, sizeof(vertices), VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT16);
        vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(renderer->commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, renderer->pipelineLayouts.color, 0, 1, renderer->sets.color + i, 0, NULL);
        vkCmdDrawIndexed(renderer->commandBuffers[i], sizeof(indices) / sizeof(indices[0]), 1, 0, 0, 0);

        vkCmdNextSubpass(renderer->commandBuffers[i], VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

        vkCmdBindPipeline(renderer->commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, renderer->pipelines.depth);
        vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(renderer->commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, renderer->pipelineLayouts.depth, 0, 1, renderer->sets.depth + i, 0, NULL);

        vkCmdDraw(renderer->commandBuffers[i], 3, 1, 0, 0);
        vkCmdEndRenderPass(renderer->commandBuffers[i]);

        vkEndCommandBuffer(renderer->commandBuffers[i]);
    }
}
```

Iv'e tried to cut the code as much as possible so `sType` and `pNext` should all be assumed to be correct.

depth_vert.spv:

```c
#version 450

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vec2((gl_VertexIndex << 1) & 2, gl_VertexIndex & 2) * 2.0f - 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

depth_frag.spv:

```c
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

layout(input_attachment_index = 0, binding = 0) uniform subpassInput inDepth;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
    outColor = vec4(vec3((subpassLoad(inDepth).r - 0.8) / 0.2), 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: I just found out that you can make swapchain images TRANSFER_DST (in imageUsage of VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR) I didn't notice that before, my bad!

Comment: I figured out what was wrong in the code, `rasterization_state.frontFace` of `pipelines.depth` should be `VK_FRONT_FACE_CLOCKWISE` or switch the x and y components of `gl_Position`. Still, I am not very happy with this approach of rendering the desired output.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is here. Seems like some debug feature or sanity check, in which case it is OK to make it suboptimal. Otherwisely you could just draw it directly to the swapchain image with something like `if( gl_FragCoord.x < half_the_window) out = color; else out = gl_FragCoord.z;`

Comment: @krOoze Yes, it is a debug feature but the question isn't about optimization, it is more about design choices so down the road I will know what is the general direction to solve similar problems. The question can be boiled down to "Am I using the Vulkan API the way it is meant to be used?"